# Passing an entire package to a snow cluster

Tags: r, parallel-processing, scope

I'm trying to parallelize (using `snow::parLapply`) some code that depends on a package (ie, a package other than `snow`). Objects referenced in the function called by `parLapply` must be explicitly passed to the cluster using `clusterExport`. Is there any way to pass an entire package to the cluster rather than having to explicitly name every function (including  a package's internal functions called by user functions!) in `clusterExport`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Install the package on all nodes, and have your code call `library(thePackageYouUse)` on all nodes via one the available commands, egg something like

```
 clusterApply(cl, library(thePackageYouUse))
```

I think the `parallel` package which comes with recent R releases has examples -- see for example here from `help(clusterApply)` where the `boot` package is loaded everywhere:

```
 ## A bootstrapping example, which can be done in many ways:
 clusterEvalQ(cl, {
   ## set up each worker.  Could also use clusterExport()
   library(boot)
   cd4.rg <- function(data, mle) MASS::mvrnorm(nrow(data), mle$m, mle$v)
   cd4.mle <- list(m = colMeans(cd4), v = var(cd4))
   NULL
 })
```

Comment: Thanks Dirk.  Are there any reasons why doing `clusterExport(ls())` would be dangerous? This wouldn't help with passing functions from packages but it would save a lot of headache to quickly parallelize for loops (someone elses, not mine!) which rely on a ton of global variables.

Comment: It's just bad design in that it uses a scattershot plus kitchen sink approach.  Design what you need in a serial solution, then make it parallel.

Comment: Some problems are tricky.  It may make sense to have each node acquire its data rather than shipping it from the master, but sometimes you can't.  It all depends -- you got to try it. When communication costs are really high relative to computation costs, your gains will be limited. The r-sig-hpc list good for more in-depth questions.

Comment: I realise this is an old post, but I think that the first suggestion (`clusterApply`) should be: `clusterCall(cl, function() library(thePackageYouUse))`

Comment: I am pretty sure I copied this from a (possibly old, but working) script.  The *intent* is clear: get the needed package loaded on each worker node.

Comment: If I do this, the CRAN package check complains about the library call. What can I do about this? Is there any other way to do the same thing?

Comment: In a package, use Imports: in DESCRIPTION and importFrom() in NAMESPACE.