# parallel::clusterExport - non exported library/package function

Tags: r, parallel-processing, testthat

similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12232629/passing-an-entire-package-to-a-snow-cluster)

But how do I `clusterExport` a package's non-exported function to a cluster? For some reason this passed [my tests](https://github.com/alexWhitworth/imputeMulti/blob/master/tests/testthat/test-count_levels.R#L62) before submitting to CRAN but isn't working in production. Obviously, I want to fix and resubmit to CRAN.

```
library(imputeMulti)
library(parallel)
imputeMulti:::count_compare # function to be exported

nnodes <- 2L
cl <- parallel::makeCluster(nnodes)    

parallel::clusterExport(cl, varlist= c("count_compare")) # fails -- but initially passed tests
parallel::clusterExport(cl, varlist= c("count_compare"), envir= as.environment("package:imputeMulti")) # also fails
```

I'm using cluster export to avoid the CRAN/R CMD check note "use of `:::` in package". Obviously, I could export `count_compare`, but that's not a desirable choice.

Any help appreciated!

#### adding tests information:

```
devtools::test("imputeMulti", "count_levels")
Loading imputeMulti
Testing imputeMulti
int- count_levels works: ...............................

DONE ===========================================================================================================================================
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an equivalent call to `clusterCall` to do this.

```
parallel::clusterCall(cl, assign, "count_compare", count_compare, envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

See the definition of [`clusterExport`](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/af7f52f70101960861e5d995d3a4bec010bc89e6/src/library/parallel/R/clusterApply.R#L70-L78) to verify this is doing the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my tests and work, I do not see away to use `parallel::clusterExport` on a non-exported library function.

The following works, but results in 1 R CMD check note:

> R CMD check results 
>   0 errors | 0 warnings | 1 note 
>   checking dependencies in R code ... NOTE 
>   There are ::: calls to the package's namespace in its code. A package
>     almost never needs to use ::: for its own objects:
>     'count_compare'

```
count_compare <- imputeMulti:::count_compare 
parallel::clusterExport(cl, varlist= c("count_compare"), envir= 1)
```

Perhaps one of the developers of `library(testthat)` can provide a solution / update regarding the problem with the `testthat` framework not catching this. Based off of [Hadley's R-Journal article](https://journal.r-project.org/archive/2011-1/RJournal_2011-1_Wickham.pdf) (pg7 using journal numbering), I'm guessing this has to do with how environments are used for testing. But, that's just a guess.

**Note**: Hadley has confirmed this is the reason for the `testthat` miss via email correspondence.